# Calculate the Hopf-Lax function explicitly

Tags: partial-differential-equations, supremum-and-infimum, cauchy-problem, hamilton-jacobi-equation

The Cauchy problem I'm dealing with leads to the following Hopf-Lax function:

$$u(t,x) = \inf_{y\in \mathbb{R}} \left\{  2|y|^2 + \frac{|x-y|^2}{2t} \right\},$$

but I don't know how to explicitly calculate this infimum. Could any solutions be step by step, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the absolute values if everything is real, so you're looking for the minimum of a quadratic in $y$.  As long as $2 + 1/(2t) > 0$, the $y^2$ term in this quadratic is positive, so the critical point is a minimum.  You can find it by the usual calculus method: take the derivative, set it to $0$, and solve.  But if $2 + 1/(2t) < 0$ (or $=0$ with $x \ne 0$), the infimum will be $-\infty$.